# ¿Cómo puedo extraer o recorrer un string que deriva de un formato XML, en PHP?

Tags: php, array, json, xml

Recibo de una API este item, el documento de la API dice:
"Cadena que contiene la
información de los atributos del
producto. Esta cadena es un array
serializado en JSON."

Y este es un respuesta de ese atributo:

```
"xmlAttributes": "{\"ListaAtributos\":{\"Atributos\":{\"attributecs\":[{\"AttributeName\":\"CONDICIÓN\",\"AttributeValue\":\"NUEVO\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"MARCA\",\"AttributeValue\":\"TP-LINK\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"MODELO\",\"AttributeValue\":\"UE200\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"LÍNEA DE PRODUCTOS\",\"AttributeValue\":\"Adaptador de Red\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"FUENTE DEL PRODUCTO\",\"AttributeValue\":\"NA\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"ES KIT\",\"AttributeValue\":\"NO\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"BOTON\",\"AttributeValue\":\"NO\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"VELOCIDAD DE TRANSFERENCIA DE DATOS\",\"AttributeValue\":\"10/1000 MBPS 2.0\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"UNIDADES DE DIMENSIÓN\",\"AttributeValue\":\"MM\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"TIPOS DE FRECUENCIAS\",\"AttributeValue\":\"NA\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"CON INDICADOR LED\",\"AttributeValue\":\"NO\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"TIPO DE ANTENA\",\"AttributeValue\":\"NA\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"TECNOLOGÍA DE MODULACIÓN\",\"AttributeValue\":\"NA\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"TECNOLOGÍA DE CONECTIVIDAD\",\"AttributeValue\":\"USB A RJ\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"SENSIBILIDAD DE RECEPCION\",\"AttributeValue\":\"NA\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"SEGURIDAD INALÁMBRICA\",\"AttributeValue\":\"NA\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"ESTANDARES\",\"AttributeValue\":\"1 Puerto Ethernet RJ45 10/100Mbps\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"FRECUENCIA\",\"AttributeValue\":\"NA\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"MODOS INALÁMBRICOS\",\"AttributeValue\":\"NA\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"PROTOCOLOS\",\"AttributeValue\":\"NA\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"UNIDAD DE PESO\",\"AttributeValue\":\"KG\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"INTERFAZ\",\"AttributeValue\":\"\\t1 Puerto USB 2.0\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"SKU\",\"AttributeValue\":\"UE200\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"NOMBRE O DESCRIPCION\",\"AttributeValue\":\"Adaptador de red USB 2.0 a Ethernet, 1 conector  USB 2.0, 1 Puerto de 100Mbps Ethernet,Sistema Plug and Play Compatible con Windows (XP/Vista/7/8/8.1), Mac OS X (10.9 and later), Linux OS, Diseño plegable y portátil.\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"CARACTERISTICAS\",\"AttributeValue\":\"Adaptador de red USB 2.0 a Ethernet, 1 conector  USB 2.0, 1 Puerto de 100Mbps Ethernet,Sistema Plug and Play Compatible con Windows (XP/Vista/7/8/8.1), Mac OS X (10.9 and later), Linux OS, Diseño plegable y portátil.\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"IMAGEN\",\"AttributeValue\":\"SI\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"EAN\",\"AttributeValue\":\"6935364094614\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"SKU SIMPLE\",\"AttributeValue\":\"UE200\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"PRECIO\",\"AttributeValue\":\"N/A\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"STOCK\",\"AttributeValue\":\"N/A\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"MÉTODO DE ENVÍO\",\"AttributeValue\":\"N/A\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"ANCHURA DEL PAQUETE DE ENVÍO\",\"AttributeValue\":\"26\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"ALTURA DEL PAQUETE DE ENVÍO\",\"AttributeValue\":\"71\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"LARGO DEL PAQUETE DE ENVÍO\",\"AttributeValue\":\"17\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"PESO DEL PAQUETE\",\"AttributeValue\":\"1\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"CANAL EXCLUSIVO\",\"AttributeValue\":\"SI\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"PRODUCTO NUEVO\",\"AttributeValue\":\"SI\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"NOMBRE\",\"AttributeValue\":\"Adaptador de Red USB 2.0 a Ethernet a 100Mbps\"}]}}}"
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problemas o errores tienes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digamos que el array serializado   a `Json` debes convertirlo a un array que `PHP` pueda entender  entonces:

Utilizamos la función  `$Arecorrer = json_decode($array_json);`   o Si quiere que el array sea asociativo utiliza  `$Arecorrer = json_decode($array_json,true);`

La forma de recorrer los array resultantes es diferente dependiento si el array lo has indicado asociativo o no

**Como recorrer un array asociativo**

Hay muchas manera pero la que voy a explicar es con un `foreach`

```html
foreach($Arecorrer as $key => $value){
  //la forma de acceder a las llaves de los arreglos asociativos es la siguiente
  
   echo $value["llave"];

  //si esta anidada (un array adentro de otro array)
   echo $value["llave"]["otrallave"];

}
```

**Como recorrer un objeto Array**

```html
foreach($Arecorrer as $key => $value){
  //la forma de acceder a las llaves de los arreglos asociativos es la siguiente
  
   echo $value->llave;

  //si esta anidada (un array adentro de otro array)
   echo $value->llave->otrallave;

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Wilfredo, con la función json_decode  que usted sugirió resolví el problema.